# AngularJS Japanese characters does not show up

Tags: angularjs

**Controller**

```
app.controller('infoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.companies = [
        {
            name: "日本語",
            id: '1',
            state: false
        },
     {
        name: "blaa",
        id: '2',
        state: false
    }
    ];

    $scope.showHide = function(c) {
        c.state = !c.state;
    };

}]);
```

and this in my html:

```
 <li ng-repeat="company in companies"> <p class="ng-cloak" style="display: inline">{{company.name}}</p>
    <a class="showLink" ng-click="showHide(company)" href="">もっと情報</a>
```

...

however, the company.name is displayed as ???? but any other japanese text is displayed just fine. Can you tell me what is the reason and how to fix it?
I have included UTF8 in my html file.

Comment: Seems fine for me http://plnkr.co/edit/g8g86vKcjtevrLXQhlYY?p=preview I think your machine should have installed have that font

Comment: oh ok, thanks! but for example if a user has the same configuration for his machine as mine and it displays it as "???", how can I fix that?
and if my machine is the problem, why everything else works ok?

Comment: @Polly You'll want to load the font in via CSS or use a web friendly Japanese font. Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563064/japanese-standard-web-fonts

Comment: thank you! I will give it a try! = )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use UTF-8 encoding for your javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem of `Angular`, it's a problem with your encoding! Looks like your `*.js` file is encoded in wrong encoding. To do it just open your file with notepad++, press Encoding Tab on the top of notepad++ and press encode in UTF-8.

Comment: so it turned out problem is the IDE that I am using, because even when saving it with notepad it changes it after, thank you very much! = )