# Japanese characters have some spaces display in google chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I've been finding a solution for this problem. I wonder why chrome displays some spaces and font changes for the japanese characters in my website like this:

[Google Chrome displaying the Japanese text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5C2p.png)
While in Microsoft Edge and Mozilla Firefox is working fine:
[Mozilla and Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcZ0z.png)

Any help will do. Thank you.

Chrome version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit)
Firefox version 53.0 (32-bit)
Edge version 38.14393.1066.0

Comment: Found already the solution for this issue. I use the standard font family for Japanese characters like MS PGothic and now i dont have problem anymore with the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Found already the solution for this issue. I use the standard font family for Japanese characters like MS PGothic and now i dont have problem anymore with the spacing.

Link here:
[Japanese standard web fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563064/japanese-standard-web-fonts)